# While access preview API for Sitecore Content Hub, getting "HTTP ERROR 401" This page isn’t working error

Tags: content-hub

While access preview API `https://my.stylelabsdemo.com/api/graphql/preview/v1` for Sitecore Content Hub 4 sandbox enviornment, getting "HTTP ERROR 401" This page isn’t working error.

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

We need to enable the publishing before using GraphQL endpoints.

- Open /admin/settingmanagement
- Search for publishingSettings
- Enable the publishing
- Publish Schema

[image]

IDE: https://my.stylelabs.io/api/graphql/preview/ide/

Make sure you are passing in "X-GQL-Token" in the headers.

[image]

This can be created from

- admin/api-keys
- On the specific content collection itself

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have already checked this but I was not able to create a new API key. On clicking on the "Create" button, nothing happens.

Comment: The question did not mention anything about API key generation issue. There is a known issue if you are on CH4.0 its fixed in CH4.0.1. Please raise a support ticket if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. Yes, I am on CH4.0 and got to know that API creation is a known issue. I will raise a support ticket.

Comment: Are you sure that this feature is available in the sandbox environment? I guess it is not. I raised a Sitecore support ticket and they responded back that sandbox environments are not under sitecore support.

Comment: If its sandbox, upgrade it to 4.0.1 and its solved already there.