# Unable to create API Key

Tags: content-hub, cmp

I have superuser access and created a `CMP Content Collection`. Added an existing item of `Type - Advertisement`.
When I try to create an API key, it does nothing.

In the console I see this error -

> 500 "An internal server error occurred"

.

[image]

In the `PublishingSettings", both "Publishing enabled" & "Auto publishing enabled" are checked.
I have clicked on both "Publish schema" & "Publish to Caas".

[image]

1. Please let me know what do these two CTAs ("Publish schema" & "Publish to Caas") do and when to use which. Is there an order of publish among these two.

If we have to do a parallel comparison with Sitecore CMS, is "Publish to Caas" like "Publish to web". If yes, then what is Publishing Schema.

2. How to fix the API Key creation error.

When I load the content collection page, there is an error. Would this be related?

[image]

We have only one environment for Content Hub and its content is being used in live sites. So, this may not be a Sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

If you see the document provided for the `Sitecore Content hub`, here are the steps to configure your publishing settings given in this reference document.

[Configure the publishing settings](https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/42/content-hub/deliver-content--configure-the-publishing-settings.html)

The final steps say about these options are given below.

- Click `Publish schema` to publish changes to the schema.
- Click `Publish all to CaaS` to publish all publishable entities

And for your error, if you see the conversation given in the below thread, you will get to know that API creation is a known issue. So if you are using 4.0 sandbox then upgrade it to 4.0.1 and its solved already there.

[While access preview API for Sitecore Content Hub, getting "HTTP ERROR 401" This page isn’t working error](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/29175/while-access-preview-api-for-sitecore-content-hub-getting-http-error-401-this)

Comment: The steps specified in the doc are obvious. I wanted to understand what they do and when. A parallel comparision to Sitecore CMS would have been helpful. The Environment is not a sandbox is being used for content on live sites. Is there a way I can confirm the version and if it is sandbox. Also, cd u pls specify how to go abt upgrading. Thank you.